# How to recover a recently saved powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, file-recovery, winrar

I saved a powerpoint 10 minutes ago, and now i can only open older versions of it. Neither can i find it anywhere else, including "recent" under file options. I have one of 2 versions saved in a winrar archive, could it have overwritten it?

I was defragging as i saved the document.

Answer (score -1):

I am afraid you may of lost your work. Either PowerPoint didn't save it correctly or the defragmentation during your saving may of effected it.

I doubt this method however you could still try it. See if there was a system recovery point maybe at the start of the defragment.